# Can you recommend good Excel spreadsheet templates for tracking spending?

Tags: spending, tracking

I did use Microsoft Money to track my spending couple of years ago, then I switched to paper and pen and then switch to online money sites such as Wesabe, but none of them really worked out. The closest was the pen-paper system, because I could create my own way of working out how much I spent. The problem with it was that I could not see right away, how much I spent during the month, only at the end when I summed up the numbers.

I like using Excel, because it is still flexible, just like the paper and I can see the sums of each spending category as the month progress.

I am looking for examples of Excel spreadsheets that can be used for tracking personal spending.

I need the following:

- Automatic category assignment as I type in payee the rest is looked up from a table.
- Budgets, so I can put in my budgets and see a summary for the given month and indication if I go over my budget.

Comment: It's not a spreadsheet, but I like Mint.com does both of the above.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure you are going to find anything like this in Excel - with the automatic lookup in specific.

Microsoft has a [template](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/templates/TC062062791033.aspx) available; but it looks to be a pretty *busy* page.

Why not look at other software?  If you have a PC, Quicken and Microsoft Money are of course the big guns.  You don't mention why you switched away from MS Money...

There are many other packages as well.  The one that I use (but have no other financial interest in) is [Moneydance](http://moneydance.com/) as it was the best on Mac at the time I was looking.  It also runs on Windows and Linux.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will check them out. My criteria for application is to have an easy way to enter transactions. Easy means to have a client on mobile. At the moment I carry a basic Nokia handset that cannot really run anything :(

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain how well this would fit your needs but have you taken a look at PearBudget? It is a pretty detailed Excel template.

https://www.pearbudget.com/spreadsheet